# "status-aceito" não deveria ser "estado-deferido"?

Tags: debate, status-recusado, tradução, meta-tags

Nas meta-tags, particularmente a [status-aceito](/questions/tagged/status-aceito), o nome da mesma é um pouco ambiguo em relação ao seu significado, e confesso que tive que ir pesquisar para entender o que a mesma significava quando aplicada nas perguntas.

O sumário da mesma não ajuda, mas ajudou a presença de um sinónimo:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Dada toda esta dificuldade que tive para identificar a mesma, venho sugerir a passagem de "aceito" para "deferido" que [**significa**](http://www.significados.com.br/deferido/):

> Deferido é o particípio passado do verbo deferir, cujo significado é dar parecer favorável a uma solicitação de algo. Dar deferimento é o ato de aprovação ou concessão de um pedido ou requerimento.

## Ficando assim [status-deferido](/questions/tagged/status-deferido)

---

Mas existe um outro aspecto que não sei a razão da existência do mesmo, que é o uso de "status" ao invés de "estado". Não sei se relacionado com o "sistema" global da SE ou se por preferência de quem participou na tomada de decisão.

Contudo, deixo a sugestão de passar "status" para "estado":

[estado-deferido](/questions/tagged/estado-deferido)

<sup>**Nota:**

A formatação das tags não assume a cor correta devido à não identificação das novas sugeridas (não fazem parte das meta-tags, pelo que ficam formatadas como se fossem tags regulares).</sup>

Comment: Será uma diferença cultural? Acredito que status-aceito seja bem claro para os brasileiros. "status" é o que geralmente se usa (em latim mesmo) em softwares, e "aceito" é mais comum (e menos formal) que "deferido".

Comment: @bfavaretto Pois, não sei se "do vosso lado" é claro o suficiente... também me passou pela cabeça esse cenário de diferença cultural! Contudo, nada como um bom debate sobre o assunto para eu aprender mais um bocadinho :)

Comment: A questão é a diferença ténue que existe entre algo "aceite" e algo "deferido". Em suma, **aceite**: é como aprovado e vai ser feito dessa forma; **deferido**: a ideia é boa e ficou na caixinha de sugestões para melhoramento, discussão e implementação futura.

Comment: O fato é que não há tradução boa. Ambos tem razão. Entendo qualquer um. E o "status" é tão bom quanto o "estado". Eu sei que em Portugal há maior tendência para traduzir tudo, enquanto que no Brasil se adota o inglês facilmente e talvez exageradamente (não nos preocupamos com a língua :) ). Acho que ambos depende mais de gosto e *background* :) do tradutor.

Comment: @Zuul, parece que status-deferido é mesmo a melhor ideia. Queres responder e assim fica esta discussão votada e documentada?

Answer (score 5):

De forma a se chegar a um meio termo entre as diferenças culturais existentes entre utilizadores Brasileiros e utilizadores Portugueses, a minha sugestão será o uso da meta tag:

[status-deferido](/questions/tagged/status-deferido)

Answer (score 1):

Sendo que estado vem do latim

> *status*: modo de estar, situação, condição

Eu vejo "*status*" como a origem da palavra **estado** e não como a versão adoptada do inglês *status*.

Assim sugiro: ***status-aceite***

<sup>Porém seria interessante ver se há sugestões diferentes, e votar juntos a melhor</sup>

Comment: "Aceite" soa bem estranho aqui no Brasil ("aceite" é substantivo, "aceito" é adjetivo).

Comment: @bfavaretto O pior é que essas palavras estão corretas, só fica estranho para os brasileiros.

Comment: Eu sei. Talvez "status-deferido" seja o melhor meio-termo. @bigown

Comment: @bfavaretto, interessante. Desconhecia :) Vou apagar a resposta. Concordo com "status-deferido"!

Comment: Deixa a resposta, @Sergio, é boa para situar quem mais aparecer por aqui.

Comment: Concordo com @bfavaretto, não elimines a resposta, a mesma é boa para recolher opiniões. Segui a tua sugestão e coloquei uma resposta sugerindo o meio termo _status-deferido_.

Comment: Ok. Aqui fica então.