# “status-bydesign” deveria ser “status-intencional”?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução, meta-tags

Na mesma linha [deste outro debate](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/437), será que a meta-tag [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) deveria se chamar `status-intencional`, ou talvez `estado-intencional`?

O que acham?

Comment: Ah, e me avisem se eu estiver sendo um chato de postar tanta miudeza aqui...

Comment: Esse tipo não. O único caso que não gosto é quando colocam qualquer traduçãozinha isolada. Mas não vou arrancar os cabelos por causa disso também. O chato é que teremos muitos problemas de tradução, se fizer uma para cada palavra que não está bem traduzida, polui demais. Nem precisa guardar dezenas de problemas para abrir uma pergunta nova também.

Comment: Eu [também acho](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/#87) que deveríamos ter uma forma melhor de organizar a contribuição da comunidade ao processo tradução, @bigown

Comment: *O único caso que não gosto é quando colocam qualquer traduçãozinha isolada.* Concordo, [mas um pouco de humor faz bem também](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/434) :) @bigown

Answer (score 3):

Sou a favor da tradução.

E prefiro `status-intencional`.