# Marcadores (tags) status-pronto, status-aceito, etc

Tags: debate, status-pronto, localização, tags

Até aonde sei o termo `status` não é uma palavra do Português

Relacionados:

- [“status-aceito” não deveria ser “estado-deferido”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/437/3635)
- [“status-bydesign” deveria ser “status-intencional”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/450/3635)

Ou o uso da palavra status é algum "neologismo" (não sei se este é o melhor termo), no caso "estamos" usando:

- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)
- [status-nãorepro](/questions/tagged/status-n%c3%a3orepro)
- [status-aceito](/questions/tagged/status-aceito)
- [status-futuro](/questions/tagged/status-futuro)
- [status-recusado](/questions/tagged/status-recusado)
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) (exceto esta que está em inglês)

Eu não sei qual termo sugerir, talvez usar "situação-" ou "estado-"

Ou isto se trata de um "neologismo", então podemos manter desta maneira?

Comment: Acho que a palavra "status" está tão presente em nosso dia-a-dia que "estado" ficaria bem mais estranho.

Comment: Acho que não deveria mudar. É uma palavra quase aportuguesada, assim como 'ok', 'chat'. Tem gente até escrevendo 'estatus' como aportuguesada mesmo.

Comment: Status é aceitável porque é inglês. Assim como layout

Comment: @JorgeB. entendo, mas vejo que palavras unidas é que ficam estranhas, no caso layout não está seguida de palavras em Portugues. Seguindo o que o bfavaretto disse, esta palavra existe sim no Portugues (ao menos encontrei no dicionário) :)

Comment: É capaz, alguns estrangeirismos passam pro dicionário. Eu não suporto é coisas como "leiaute".

Comment: Cara eu também não suporto "leiaute" e "vou fazer o designe**R** do site" :( isso mata kkkkkkk

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sabes que "esporte" veio de "sport" não sabes? ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Não sabia :O - Mas, não sei se estamos falando do "designeR", mas é que "ER" faz a palavra ser tipo: "desenhista" - "Eu vou fazer o desenhista do site" é estranho kk

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento e porque não "Eu vou fazer o *design* do site já que eu sou *designer* "?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A palavra *status* é do Latim, e foi importada tanto na língua inglesa, quanto no português (embora [oficialmente](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23) seja sim um estrangeirismo).

Por isso eu acho tranquilo manter *status*, acho que é claro pra todo mundo. No caso de *status-bydesign*, poderia mesmo ser *status-intencional*. Sobre *status-aceito*, prefiro "aceito" que "deferido" – afinal aqui não é um cartório :)

Comment: Realmente existe.

Comment: Mete me uma confusão o "aceito"...

Comment: @JorgeB. Se fosse "aceite", meter-nos-ia uma confusão a nós brasileiros ;)

Comment: Eu sei  @bfavaretto estava só a desabafar :P

Comment: `status-bydesign` vai virar `status-intencional` hoje mais tarde. Já `status-aceito` vai ficar `status-aceito` :D